# How to differentiate between pynput and keyboard/mouse inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, driver, pynput

Assume the following code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from time import sleep

def onPress(key):
    if key == Key.space: 
        print("Hi")

keyboardController = Controller()

keyboardListener = Listener(on_press=onPress)
keyboardListener.start()

while True:  
    sleep(5)
    keyboardController.press(Key.space)
```

This will print "Hi" everytime I press space on my keyboard but also every 5 seconds.

Some games are able to "ignore" keyboard/mouse inputs which are generated using the keybd_event function (This is what pynput uses to generate WM_KEYUP/WM_KEYDOWN messages afaik). However, the keyboard listener in pynput does not seem to be able to distinguish between "driver key press messages" (?) and keybd_events. Is there a way to only listen to real keyboard key presses? (Preferably using pynput but if thats not possible other solutions are highly welcomed as well)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is wondering how this could be solved:

win32_event_filter seems to provide a possible solution for this. You can check if `data.flags == 16`, if true the key press has been injected otherwise its most likely a physical key press. However, there are "false positives" for injected modifier key presses.